# Pattern matching 4 fixed letters followed by any 6 digits

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset with a column in which I need to find whether a particular patterns exists.

Example database:

```
DF <- data.frame(TextCol = c("Card number is GIFT987654","GIFT564738","no card number","543gift111111","number:gift9384730"))
```

What I need to do is to add another columns which says Yes or No depending on if there is the following pattern match:

first 4 characters are fixed - "GIFT", followed by exactly 6 numbers (any digits from 0 to 9)

So I need the following dataframe as the result:

```
DF <- data.frame(TextCol = c("Card number is GIFT987654","GIFT564738","no card number","543gift111111","number:gift9384730"), Match = c("Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `grepl("GIFT\\d{6}|gift\\d{6}", DF$TextCol)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic,

```r
DF$yesno1 <- grepl("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}", DF$TextCol)              # if any four-letters works
DF$yesno2 <- grepl("GIFT[0-9]{6}", DF$TextCol, ignore.case = TRUE) # verbatim, case-insens
DF$yesno3 <- grepl("(GIFT|gift)[0-9]{6}", DF$TextCol)              # another way
DF
#                     TextCol yesno1 yesno2 yesno3
# 1 Card number is GIFT987654   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 2                GIFT564738   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 3            no card number  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 4             543gift111111   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 5        number:gift9384730   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

The regular expression trick here is knowing that `{m,n}` will find between `m` and `n` instances of the previous pattern (`[0-9]` here). `{m,}` means at least `m`, `{,n}` means at most `n`, and `{m}` means exactly `m`.

In R, I tend to prefer `logical` types instead of strings to indicate boolean conditions, but if you really need it to be `"yes"` and `"no"`, then `ifelse(x, "yes", "no")` on which solution you want should work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexpr`.

```
transform(DF, Match=ifelse(as.numeric(regexpr("GIFT|gift\\d{6}", DF$TextCol)) > 0, "yes", "no"))
#                     TextCol Match
# 1 Card number is GIFT987654   yes
# 2                GIFT564738   yes
# 3            no card number    no
# 4             543gift111111   yes
# 5        number:gift9384730   yes
```